# The sender does not match the digital signature

Tags: c#, encryption, mimekit

I am using Mime kit for send mail and encryption. The code is,

```
               var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test", "xxx@gmail.com"));
            //message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Sub", "ss@gmail.com"));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test Mail", "xx@gmail.com"));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test", "yyu@gmail.com"));
            //message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test Mail", "yyy@gmail.com"));
            message.Subject = "TEST";


            var body = new TextPart("plain")
            {
                Text = "Sample comments"
            };

            var attachment = new MimeKit.MimePart()
            {
                Content = new MimeContent(File.OpenRead(filePath), ContentEncoding.Default),
                ContentDisposition = new ContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.Attachment),
                ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
            };

            var multipart = new Multipart("mixed");
            multipart.Add(body);
            multipart.Add(attachment);
            message.Body = multipart;

            var signCertificateFile = @"E:\D_RSA.pfx";
            var signcertificate = new X509Certificate2(signCertificateFile, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            var certificateFile = @"E:\D_RSA.crt";
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateFile, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            var recipientCollection = new MimeKit.Cryptography.CmsRecipientCollection();
            var bountyRecipientCertificate = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certificate);

            var recipient = new CmsRecipient(bountyRecipientCertificate);
            recipient.EncryptionAlgorithms = new EncryptionAlgorithm[] { EncryptionAlgorithm.Aes256 };
            recipientCollection.Add(recipient);
            using (var ctx = new TemporarySecureMimeContext())
            {
                var encrypted = ApplicationPkcs7Mime.Encrypt(ctx, recipientCollection, message.Body);                    
                var signer = new CmsSigner(signcertificate);
                signer.DigestAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithm.Sha256;
                message.Body = MultipartSigned.Create(ctx, signer, encrypted);
            }
            using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
            {
                client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 25, false);

                client.Authenticate("xxx@gmail.com", "xxx");

                client.Send(message);
                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
```

The message encrypted and successfully delivered. But got error in email
'The sender does not match the digital signature'.

[image]

Any idea about this error? I am using RSA certificates and  MimeKit for email encryption.

Comment: Does the email address in the certificate match the email address that you used to send the message? What does the "Sender Info" link in your screenshot say if you click on it?

Comment: Sender info contain a .pem file. it's does not have any key

Comment: I guarantee that the email address that you used did not match the email address of the certificate.